# What would be the ideal amount of RAM for processing large datasets in Weka?

Tags: memory, weka, ram, allocation

I am working on a project about anomaly-based intrusion detection and I am trying to use Weka to test some ML single classifiers and ensemble methods against the MQTT-IoT dataset. Two of the .csv files are quite large, each containing over one million entries. My PC was only just able to load these into the application to display everything, but this is using all 16BG of my RAM as well as having to use VRAM which slows everything down further. A couple of solutions I think might work are:

A) Get more RAM, will 32BG be sufficient though? I feel like once I actually start training a model things might start to blast off to space

B) Use a smaller sample of my dataset. This would make sense but I am relatively new to the subject of machine learning and have been told that I must be careful doing this so as not to affect the correlation between my features. I am also not that well versed in the methods for doing this as I don't imagine I can just copy and paste out smaller chunks.

C) Create a VM with loads of RAM on azure and use that for my more demanding tests.

Any suggestions/Help regarding any of these options would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer to that.

Different algorithms require different amounts of memory due to their internal data structures. Also, the types of attributes can influence the memory consumption as nominal attributes may get converted into multiple binary ones, potentially exploding the number of attributes in your data matrix.

Don't use the GUI for memory intensive tasks, as it will keep copies of the data for visualization etc. The command-line is better suited in terms of memory consumption.

You could try supervised sub-sampling to keep the class distribution similar when generating subsets of your data:
https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/filters/supervised/instance/Resample.html

Also, try incremental algorithms, as they don't have to load the data into memory for training:
https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/UpdateableClassifier.html

Of course, don't use cross-validation as you would have to keep the data in memory to generate the folds, defeating the incremental approach.

Last, but not least: more memory is always good for machine learning.